# No signature in the WS-Security message for the configured soap actor/role ""! (from client)

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm binding as follows

```
    //Get certificate in bytes[]
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            localCert = new X509Certificate2(cert.File, "mypassword");
            store.Add(localCert);
            certFriendlyName = localCert.FriendlyName;

            //set binding
            SecurityBindingElement security = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
            X509SecurityTokenParameters item = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Any, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient);
            security.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted.Add(item);
            security.IncludeTimestamp = false;
            security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;
            TextMessageEncodingBindingElement encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
            HttpsTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            transport.RequireClientCertificate = true;
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding currentBinding = new CustomBinding(security, encoding, transport);
             EndpointIdentity identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("mydns");
             EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("MyURI"), identity);


            service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My , X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certFriendlyName);
             service.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                                                                                           System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
                                                                                           System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                                                                                           certFriendlyName);
```

and below is the security policy from the provided WSDL

```
<wsp:Policy Name="GAPolicy" wsu:Id="policy.ga" xmlns:wsaws="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <wsaws:UsingAddressing xmlns:wsaws="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" />
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>

<wsp:Policy Name="NPPIPolicy" wsu:Id="policy.nppi"
    xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <!-- Force the use of WS-Addressing -->
            <wsaws:UsingAddressing xmlns:wsaws="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" />

            <!-- Require a signature on the body of the message -->
            <wsp:SignedParts>
                <wsp:Body />
            </wsp:SignedParts>

            <!-- X.509 Certs in header -->
            <wsp:AsymmetricBinding
                xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:InitiatorSignatureToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:X509Token
                                    sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorSignatureToken>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never" />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <!-- Supported encryption algorithms -->
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                                <sp:Basic256 />
                                <sp:TripleDes />
                                <sp:TripleDesSha256 />
                                <sp:TripleDesSha256Rsa15 />
                            </wsp:ExactlyOne>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <!-- Do not impose an order of layout -->
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Lax />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </wsp:AsymmetricBinding>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>

<wsp:Policy Name="PCIPolicy" wsu:Id="policy.pci"
    xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <!-- Force the use of WS-Addressing -->
            <wsaws:UsingAddressing xmlns:wsaws="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" />

            <!-- Require a signature on the body of the message -->
            <wsp:SignedParts>
                <wsp:Body />
            </wsp:SignedParts>

            <!-- X.509 Certs in header -->
            <wsp:AsymmetricBinding
                xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:InitiatorSignatureToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:X509Token
                                    sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorSignatureToken>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never" />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <!-- Supported encryption algorithms -->
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                                <sp:Basic256 />
                                <sp:TripleDes />
                                <sp:TripleDesSha256 />
                                <sp:TripleDesSha256Rsa15 />
                            </wsp:ExactlyOne>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <!-- Do not impose an order of layout -->
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Lax />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </wsp:AsymmetricBinding>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Using this I'm running into "System.ServiceModel.FaultException: No signature in the WS-Security message for the configured soap actor/role ""! (from client)"

Answer (score -1):

Use CustomBinding directly. By introducing WsHttpBinding and setting its security to expect client certificate you are configuring completely different security mode. I wrote an [article about this issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20151023121334/http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/08/signing-without-primary-signature-requires-timestamp/) (as a result of the question on MSDN you've already found). Start with the binding described in the article or modify it according to your needs. The described binding uses mutual HTTPS (client certificate for HTTPS) with supporting certificate in each request message.

Comment: sounds good, the binding seems to work fine when i ran it against the soapui mock service, I'll update you on my other tests

Comment: i changed the binging as per article but now I'm running into " Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: No signature in the WS-Security message for the configured soap actor/role ""! (from client)"

Comment: Modify your question - add your current binding and show security policy part of your WSDL. Also make sure that both client and server use the same configuration! There should be no signature at all - my binding doesn't expect any.